# Математические операции над элементами массива в файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, файлы, numpy

У меня есть CSV файл - таблица с численными данными. Нужно отнормировать все элементы файла, поделить каждый элемент таблицы на максимальное число из таблицы.

Как это корректно сделать?

Прилагаю кусок кода:

Перед нормировкой проводилось транспонирование, это нужно для других целей, не для нормировки. Ошибки возникают на этапе нормировки.

```
# Транспонирование таблицы
def read_data():
    data = []
    with open("faila.csv") as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            data.append(list(map(float, line.rstrip().split(";"))))
    return np.array(data).T

data = read_data()
```

Нормировка:

```
# Нормирование элементов
def norm_data():
    spisok = []
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        normirovka = np.array(data)/100  # число 100 - это то число, на которое нормировали
        spisok.append(normirovka)
    return spisok

spisok = norm_data()
```

Выдавалась такая ошибка:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-5957c118a118> in <module>
      6     return spisok
      7 
----> 8 spisok = norm_data()
      9 
     10 # #---------------------------ПРИМЕР

<ipython-input-68-5957c118a118> in norm_data()
      2     spisok = []
      3     for i in range(0,len(data)):
----> 4         normirovka = np.array(data)/100
      5         spisok.append(normirovka)
      6     return spisok

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 13.7 MiB for an array with shape (500, 3601) and data type float64
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: У вас память похоже кончается, это странно. А вообще как-то не логично смешивать обычные списки питона и `numpy.array`, работайте с чем-то одним. А ещё лучше возьмите `Pandas` и тогда чтение `csv` и работа с данными будет гораздо проще.

Comment: @Alexndr, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

В Pandas (надстройка над Numpy) это делается очень просто:

```
import pandas as pd  # conda install pandas / pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";").T
res = df / df.max().max()
print(res)
```

PS при работе с модулями на подобие Pandas / Numpy / etc. действует правило - чем меньше явных циклов и чем короче и элегантнее код, тем быстрее и эффективнее работает программа.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Поделить все элементы массива numpy на максимальное значение массива можно так:

```
data = data / data.max()
```

Ваша функция нормализации должна выглядеть так:

```
def normalize_data(data):
    return data / data.max()
```